# Can one use function style-cast expressions involving deduction of class template argument(s) freely?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Consider an example:

```
template <class T>
struct tag { 
    tag(T) {}
};

int main() {
              tag(int{});     //#1
    auto t1 = tag(int{});     //#2
    auto t3 = (tag(int{}));   //#3
}
```

`tag` has an automatic deduction guides which should be involved in deduction of the class template argument. At least I thought it should as #1 and #3 act a bit unexpectedly in [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8ZuE4TAMG17wsD0H). On the other hand everything compiles fine in [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cwPD9pOgI7OYrtA3). So the question is can I freely use deduction of class template argument in function style-cast expressions or are there any restrictions in the matter?

The error list of clang:

```
prog.cc:7:19: error: expected unqualified-id
              tag(int{});     //#1
                  ^
prog.cc:7:19: error: expected ')'
prog.cc:7:18: note: to match this '('
              tag(int{});     //#1
                 ^
prog.cc:9:23: error: expected ')'
    auto t3 = (tag(int{}));   //#3
                      ^
prog.cc:9:19: note: to match this '('
    auto t3 = (tag(int{}));   //#3
                  ^
prog.cc:9:27: error: expected expression
    auto t3 = (tag(int{}));   //#3
                          ^
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: The `operator+` is not relevant for these questions (as you focus on #1 and #4): you could minimize your MVCE to just `template <class T> struct tag { tag(T) {} };`. W.r.t. #1 and #3, I agree that it seems weird that clang doesn't accept it (as it accepts it when including and argument list), and it should relate to how the automatic deduction guides of `tag`'s ctors are applied.

Comment: @dfri Minimized, good point, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, [#34091](https://llvm.org/pr34091). Basically, clang doesn't expect to get a *template-id* there. It'll get fixed eventually (but not in 5.0.1 I'm afraid).

To answer your question, yes, gcc is completely right. I would really be angry at the standards committee if class template argument deduction wouldn't work for those two simple cases. :P

Comment: at least I won't have to file a bug report ;)